# Material Table ExportButton is missing from the options props

Tags: button, export, material-table, missing-features

I encountered an issue on MaterialTable's export button. It didn't show up in the table after adding `<MaterialTable options={{exportButton: true}} />`

I discovered that `exportButton` wasn't found in the `Options interface`, when I stepped into the `options props` in the MaterialTable. To tackle with this issue, I've tried to remove the `node_modules` folder and install it again.

Apparently, it doesn't seem to solve the issue.   This is the list of the elements shown in my `Options interface`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting *MaterialTable* `options` like this:

```js
options={{
    // ..other options
    exportButton: {
      csv: true,
      pdf: false
    }
}}
```

Here is a link to a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-export-options-evc7n?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: I've tried this, it doesn't help. The biggest problem here is exportButton could no longer find in the `MaterialTable options props`, you may click on image that i've shared above.

Comment: @jeomjeom maybe we are on different versions of `MaterialTable` ? The working sandbox I provided is using `1.69.1`.

Comment: Thanks, @NicoE. Issue solved. I was using `@material-table/core`, instead of `mbrn/material-table`. They have different props.